# how to sum after iff condition in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I want to sum all the values of the column, using if condition same as the column expression:-

The Expression of the normal column:-

```
iif(Fields!mcount.Value <> 0 And Fields!TaxCode.Value = 1 ,Fields!InputAmnt.Value,0)
```

The Expression to sum, I used 2 codes and the same result "#Error" appeared in both cases

```
sum(iif(Fields!mcount.Value <> 0 And Fields!TaxCode.Value = 1 ,Fields!InputAmnt.Value,0))
```

and

```
 iif(Fields!mcount.Value <> 0 And Fields!TaxCode.Value = 1 ,sum(Fields!InputAmnt.Value),0)
```

any help ?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or details of how the report body looks? Where are the expressions?

Comment: I wonder if you have to specify the name of a group or dataset that you're trying to sum?  Like `sum(iif(....), "<group/dataset name>")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding VAL from the InputAmnt field. See below expression.

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!mcount.Value <> 0 And Fields!TaxCode.Value = 1 ,VAL(Fields!InputAmnt.Value),0))
```

Comment: unfortunately same result :/